# Galactic Distances

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, geometry, distance

I'm trying to show:

**1 arcsec on the sky is approximately 5d parsecs at a galaxy, d parsecs away**

Could someone show me a proof of this statement, because it is bamboozling me!

Comment: Hint: pretty sure that should be "$d$ Mpc away".  Think about the definition of a parsec...

Comment: Just search for the definition of parsec.

Answer (score 0):

One radian contains this many arcseconds: $(180/\pi)\times 60^2\approx 10^6/5$.